# how to structure VueJs Views with subviews

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a large VueJs Project with many views and subviews (route-childrens).
Unfortunately I can't find any good pattern how to structure the views folder best. (incl. filenames)
Is there any best practice?

Following an example of my current :

- views

  - user

    - UserIndex.vue
    - UserShow.vue
    - subviews

      - UserRoles.vue //index-view
  - role

    - RoleIndex.vue

Comment: What about renaming the files?

Comment: Everything you want to know about how to structure a `vue.js` project can be found here: [Style Guide | Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove User Prefix from vue component, it already got User folder to recognize, After all its your choice to use which is best for your need.

```
- Views
   - User
    - Index.Vue
    - Show.Vue
    - Edit.Vue
    - Roles
      - Index.Vue 
      - Show.Vue
      - Edit.Vue
```

Comment: And what is the typescript class name? ```export default class Index extends Vue```?

Comment: I'm not good with type script ,
<script lang="ts">

export default class Index extends Vue {
 // your code
}
</script>

Go through this link might help : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-typescript-class-components